# Shared data in base class in asp.net

Tags: c#, oop

I have a set of aspx pages which are made of up usercontrols.  Each usercontrol inherits from a base class.  In that base class I want to put some common data objects (via EF) that I need access to in my user controls.  How can I do this efficiently so that each user controls accesses the same class instance or copy of the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Singleton Per Request pattern](http://dotnetslackers.com/community/blogs/simoneb/archive/2006/08/21/382.aspx). It's useful if you only want a single instance of a object to be available during the lifetime of a request.

It does this by storing the item in the `HttpContext.Items` collection.

```
public class SingletonPerRequest
{
    public static SingletonPerRequest Current
    {
        get
        {
            return (HttpContext.Current.Items["SingletonPerRequest"] ??
                (HttpContext.Current.Items["SingletonPerRequest"] = 
                new SingletonPerRequest())) as SingletonPerRequest;

        }
    }
}
```